# Why is Jenkins improperly parsing my JUnit report?

Tags: testing, junit, jenkins, continuous-integration, behat

I have a Jenkins job which runs every time I push code up to my repository.  The last step of this job is to run a series of [behat](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/) tests.  These tests output both the "pretty" formatter and the jUnit formatter.  The jUnit XML looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="default">
  <testsuite name="Confirm that the theme is enabled" tests="1" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0">
    <testcase name="Make sure all drupal regions are present on the homepage" status="passed"></testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Confirm that Drupal installed" tests="2" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0">
    <testcase name="Look for a body element on the homepage" status="passed"></testcase>
    <testcase name="Make sure users can login" status="passed"></testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Validate API" tests="2" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0">
    <testcase name="Show that service is available at /api/v1." status="passed"></testcase>
    <testcase name="Make sure the the api/v1/page_wrapper response is valid" status="passed"></testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Confirm main menu has installed properly." tests="1" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0">
    <testcase name="Confirm the main menu links are present." status="passed"></testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

So far so good. The problem is this last test, "Confirm main menu has installed properly."  This was added recently, and it never behaved like the others.  It is the only one that appears as a sibling of the root element on the test results overview page.  That is to say, when I click on "test results" I see this:

[image]

When I click on `(root)` I see all my other test results.  But when I click "Confirm main menu has installed properly" I see this:

[image: A picture of Jenkins failing to display my test cases]

Which is meaningless, and doesn't even include my testcases.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review, the problem was the period (`.`) character included in the last test result!  I just removed the period, and everything worked properly!

[image]
[image]